# Escape space character in command line argument for bash script

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a bash script that takes a comma-delimited list of file paths, parses them into an array, then performs an environment variable replace function (`[envsubst][1]`) on each of the files. One of the paths, however, contains a space, and as of right now it's not an option to rename the folder. Is there a way to escape the space in the file and pass this into my script, as a parameter, so that `second` and `path` do not wind up being interpreted as two separate variables? I've tried a number of attempts I've seen in SO/online posts including:

second\ path/file.txt

second%qpath/file.txt

'second path/file.txt'

"second path/file.txt"

Each one of these winds up with the function splitting the words 'second' and 'path/file.txt'.

**CLI**

`$sh envsub.sh first/path.txt,second path/file.txt`

**sh script**

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "${@}"

for t in ${array[@]}; do 
    envsubst < $t > "${t}_new"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you want your parameters to be parsed comma-separated, why do you have a space (which you do **not** want to separate anything) in your IFS?

Change:

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "${@}"
```

To:

```
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "${@}"
```

Voila, spaces are no longer separating parameters, and you get `${array[1]}` to contain `second path/file.txt` as desired.

Then comes the second gotcha:

```
for t in ${array[@]};
```

`${array[@]}` gets expanded to all members of `array`, which are two (separated by the first character in `IFS`), with one of them containing a space.

And since your `IFS` redefinition was for your `read` line only, `for` will now use the default, which again *includes* the space as separating character. And `for` will separate the list at the space between `second` and `path`...

So redefine IFS to include comma *only*, for both `read` and `for`:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=','
read -r -a array <<< "${@}"

for t in ${array[@]}
do 
    envsubst < $t > "${t}_new"
done
```

There you go.

Comment: Ah...... completely missed the space character. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @NealR: Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes. Replacing that `envsubst ...` with `echo $t` and adding an `echo ${array[1]}` after the `read` also helped.  ("Check your assumptions.") ;-)